# can i play videos in webview without player in swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, swift5

I want to view my video inside the WebKit and not play so that I can prevent screen recording

[image]

Comment: can you describe more that what you want to do..

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)